# How to force Skype's Panel icon to show Skype's main window in workspace 4 specifically?

Tags: gnome-panel, skype, workspaces

I would like to have Skype appear in Workspace 4 only, but sill have its Panel icon showing in all workspaces.

Skype can have several sub-windows, and I want to contain them all to Workspace 4...

The Skype's Panel icon is only in the Panel when Skype is running, so there may be two sides to this...

- starting Skype's main window for the first time via the Main Menu
- re-displaying the hidden Skype main-window by clicking the Panel icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [devilspie](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devilspie) to make all subwindows open in a particular workspace. This is a relatively easy application to use. As for the second half of the question, I don't have an answer.

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

Comment: It looks interesting... I've downloaded a GUI for it, but can't get it to work... (its too late here.... I'll look again in the morning...)